# Is there a way to make website shortcuts in the Scope or the launcher in Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, launcher, shortcuts

Is there a way to make website shortcuts in the Scope and/or the Launcher?

If not, is there a way to suggest it?

Answer (score 0):

There is already an [open feature request](https://github.com/ubports/morph-browser/issues/198) for PWA support.

For now, though, you would need to create a webapp package. You can use the [Webapp Creator](https://open-store.io/app/webapp-creator.jujuyeh) app to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make a webapp from a website is to use [Webber](https://open-store.io/app/webber.timsueberkrueb).

Puttin any app, on the launcher is just a question of doing a long press on the launcher icon when the app is open (all open apps have temporary icon on the launcher), or of dragging the icon to a new position on the launcher.